# Some troubles with date visualization

Tags: php, sql, date, phpmyadmin

I have some troubles with visualization of the date in a query with php. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname   = "alternanza";
// connessione al server sql
$conn     = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("errore nella connessione");
} else {
    echo "connessione avvenuta correttamente <Br/>";
}
// recupero dati passati dal form 
$nome    = $_POST["nome"];
$cognome = $_POST["cognome"];
$dal     = $_POST["dal"];
$al      = $_POST["al"];

$query     = "select NomeS, CognomeS, Specializzazione, Denominazione 
from studente, azienda, attivitàformativa 
where CodFiscaleS=KCodFiscaleS and CodAzienda=KodAzienda and Data_inizio='$dal' 
and Data_fine='$al' and CognomeS='$cognome' and NomeS='$nome'";
$risultato = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (!$risultato) {
    echo " errore di comando <br/>";
    exit();
}
while ($riga = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato))
    if ($riga) {
        echo "nome: " . $riga['NomeS'] . " <br/>";
        echo "cognome: " . $riga['CognomeS'] . " <br/>";
        echo "periodo stage dal: " . $riga['Data_inizio'] . " <br/>";
        echo "al: " . $riga['Data_fine'] . " <br/>";
        echo "presso azienda: " . $riga['Denominazione'] . " <br/>";
        echo "con specializzazione: " . $riga['Specializzazione'] . " <br/>";
    }
mysqli_close($conn);
echo " connessione chiusa";
?>
```

The errors I viewed are:

> Notice: Undefined index: Data_inizio(date) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\scuola18\attestato.php on line 38 periodo stage dal:
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Data_fine in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\scuola18\attestato.php on line 39 al:

Do you know something about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: You have missed `Data_fine` and `Data_inizio` in your select query

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `Data_fine` and `Data_inizio` in your select query. Your select query should look like this

```
select NomeS, Data_fine, Data_inizio,  CognomeS, Specializzazione, Denominazione 
from studente, azienda, attivitàformativa 
where CodFiscaleS=KCodFiscaleS and CodAzienda=KodAzienda and Data_inizio='$dal' 
and Data_fine='$al' and CognomeS='$cognome' and NomeS='$nome'
```

However, I suggest you to use [parepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to prevent from sql injections